# What's the purpose of "at" before "the heart"?

Tags: grammar

> Come on, it's all about patterns and variables. Oh, wait, stick with
> me.  I'm gonna take you back to sixth grade with this, okay? Godzilla
> attacks when  provoked, that's the pattern. Pensacola is the only
> coastal Apex hub  with an advanced robotics lab. That's the variable.
> And add them up  and your answer is that Apex is **at** the heart of the
> problem.

What's the purpose of "at" before "the heart" ?

Source: Godzilla vs. Kong (2021)

Comment: 'To be/lie at the heart of something' is a standard expression meaning to be right in the middle of it, or to be the most important part (as the heart is seen as the most important part of the body).

Comment: It’s an idiom https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+heart

Comment: Because **at** means "where".  The difference between "X is at the heart of the problem" vs "X is the heart of the problem" is the same as the difference between "I am at the bus station" and "I am the bus station."

Comment: You're doing it again, Bobby. You're asking simple questions about medium-level texts. You need to read simpler things and develop your English skills more.

Comment: @FeliniusRex So medium-level texts are off topic here?

Comment: @BobbyOmega You are asking *simple* questions about *medium-level* texts. You need to read simpler texts and increase your skills first. Then you'll be able to enjoy these texts instead of asking questions every page. Don't make life hard for yourself.

Comment: @FeliniusRex How can I identify **medium-level texts**?

Comment: @BobbyOmega How are you identifying what you are reading now? It's not working.